# Passing Variables in Function and compare each?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to practice Haskell returns and datatypes. I'm trying to pass the following information into the program:

```
worm = 1:2:3:worm
eel = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
snake = 3:2:1:snake
whale = [1..100]
```

And i want to create a function that has a switch function to get the data and match it to its definition. For example, in Python:

```
def compare(str): #for one case and using string to clarify
    if str == "1:2:3:worm":
       return "worm"
```

I know the datatypes are lists but causes a lot of confusion. My code is giving me an error of `Could not deduce (Num Char) Arising from use of worm`

My code:

```
which :: [a] -> String
which x | x == [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3] = "worm" | x == 3:2:1:snake = "snake" | otherwise = "F"
```

Is there another approach i'm missing? and why is my function giving me that error?

Comment: The Haskell expression `worm = 1:2:3:worm` is not the same as your python `"1:2:3:worm"`.    In python that is a string of ten characters.  In Haskell `worm` is a list of integers of infinite length.  You literally have the numbers 1, 2, and 3 appended to a list of ... the numbers 1 2 and 3 appended to a list of ... the numbers 1,2 and 3 appen...

Comment: There's also no real use to returning the name of a variable as a string; what would you do with it?

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

1. You can't have a function that returns a list of numbers sometimes and a string other times. That's literally the entire point of a strongly typed language. If you want something like that, you need to use a sum type.
2. You can't compare infinite lists. You can try, but your program will never finish.

Comment: I want my function to only return strings. just the names defined at the beginning

Comment: Besides "F", what strings do you want it to return? That's the only string you used.

Comment: Oh forgot the quotes. Sorry. Edited the question

Comment: I find it unlikely that you still get the error that you say you get, now that you made that change. And you still didn't address my second point.

Comment: Yes regarding that, what infinite lists are you referring to?

Comment: `worm` and `snake` are both infinite. `worm` is `[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,...` forever, and similarly for `snake`.

Comment: Worm has 9 elements. Is there something i'm missing? Also for snake, i thought it was a list of size 4?

Comment: Is there another approach rather than compare then? because thats what i would do in any other languages. (C/ Python/ Java)

Comment: Both of those statements are wrong, and I can't even figure out what mistake you made to come to believe them. So yes, you're definitely missing something. Try looking at those things in GHCi.

Comment: You can't compare arbitrary infinite lists in C, Python, Java, or any other programming language.

Comment: I wasn't referring to comparing infinite lists. Just comparison of a regular n-defined lists. And for that, my professor gave us this problem as practice for an exam and cannot solve it. He said they were defined lists thats where i'm basing my information

Comment: You say you're not referring to infinite lists, but the lists in your code are infinite anyway. And did you just now make up the term "n-defined lists"? If not, can you provide a reference for it?